# How to get the service principal of the Azure Active Directory Graph(not Microsoft Graph)?

Tags: azure, powershell, permissions, active-directory, devops

In the Azure Portal, I can add permissions for the 'Azure Active Directory Graph'.
However, I can't seem to find a way to do this programmatically.

`$azureActiveDirectorySvcPrincipal = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -All $true | ? { $_.DisplayName -match "Azure Active Directory Graph" }`

Returns nothing. How come I can find this in the portal, but get nothing back when using powershell?

(I know that it is recommended to Migrate to Microsoft Graph, but it has breaking changes for the application and I need to use Azure Active Directory Graph instead.)

Comment: Do you have a Service Principal by that name?

Comment: The appId of this service principal is `00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000` and the display name is `Windows Azure Active Directory`

Answer (score 0):

As Thomas has already told in comment section , The Display name of **Azure Active Directory Graph** is `Windows Azure Active Directory` and details are as below:

```
"appDisplayName": "Windows Azure Active Directory",
"appId": "00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
```

[image]

You can use Azure CLI as well to get these details.

**Command :** `az ad sp list --display-name "Windows Azure Active Directory"`